# Could not get unknown property 'android' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I am new to flutter and coding, and I have a Flutter project that uses FirebaseAuth and Firestore packages.
I keep getting an error that says

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I get the above error after inserting  `android.enableJetifier=true` and `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `android\build.gradle` file, in the dependencies block

*android\build.gradle* file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //Added from Firebase (SDK)
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        android.enableJetifier=true
        android.useAndroidX=true
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Try putting android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties file.

Comment: They are also true but i still get the same error